# Unexpected token < with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is really bothering me and I can't figure out how to solve this problem. My code that is creating the problem is this:

```
$("#add-warmup").click(function(){
    $("#warmup").empty().prepend('<td><input type="text" name="distance-warm" maxlength="7" size="4"> miles</td><td><input type="text" name="duration-warm" maxlength="8" size="8" placeholder="HH:MM:SS" /></td><td>Warmup<input type="hidden" name="type-warm" value="Warmup" /></td><td><select name="shoe-warm"><option value=""><?= str_repeat('&nbsp;', 12); ?></option>></select></td>');
>});
```

I just want to click a link and have the current row replaced with actual value for input, but I keep getting the `Unexpected token <` error on the first part of the quote. Things as simple as `.prepend('<p> test</p>');` work but this doesn.t

Comment: Show us the HMTL output, not the PHP code.

Comment: That last edit removed the issue from the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it work if you wrap what you're prepending?

```
$("#add-warmup").click(function(){

$("#warmup").empty().prepend($('<td><input type="text" name="distance-warm" maxlength="7" size="4"> miles</td> <td><input type="text" name="duration-warm" maxlength="8" size="8" placeholder="HH:MM:SS" /></td> <td>Warmup<input type="hidden" name="type-warm" value="Warmup" /></td>
<td><select name="shoe-warm"><option value=""><?= str_repeat('&nbsp;', 12); ?></option> </select></td>'));

});
```

Edit:
From your screenshot: http://gyazo.com/1f01eabd8e3acacc3eb534f5a88fc6cf.png?1365010212

AHA!  The culprit is shown!  Your text starts on the line after the opening '  See here: [Creating multiline strings in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805107/creating-multiline-strings-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing this

```
<?= str_repeat('&nbsp;', 12); ?>
```

with

```
<?= str_repeat("&nbsp;", 12); ?>
```

Comment: I tried this, it seems like the error is right from the beginning http://gyazo.com/1f01eabd8e3acacc3eb534f5a88fc6cf.png?1365010212

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with the posted code. You are using unescaped single quotes (`'`) inside of a string using single quotes. `<?= str_repeat('&nbsp;', 12); ?>` should be `<?= str_repeat(\'&nbsp;\', 12); ?>` or `<?= str_repeat("&nbsp;", 12); ?>`.

Also note the fact that you are using PHP inside your jQuery. (Unless the JS is being generated by PHP.)

But your `Unexpected token >` error is from the fact that you have an extra `>` at the closing of your function.

Comment: I don't think that matters.  PHP is parsed on the server so what will be sent out to the client will only be the 12x&nbsp;

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
.prepend('<p>test</p>');
```

Try

```
.prepend('\<p\>test\<\/p\>');
```

also try to keep your HTML that you are prepending in one line.

I also noticed when i posted this your code was full of carriage returns. Remove these as well